# Efficient algorithm to compute resultants of sparse polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, resultants

Consider two polynomials $f,g\in\mathbb{F}_2$ of degree $O(2^n)$, with the property that they are **extremely sparse** (say, only $O(n)$ of the coefficients are non-zero). Is there a way to calculate their resultant that does not involve an exponential computation in $n$? The Sylvester matrix would be very structured (more than it is already), but I don't know if there are methods to exploit this structure to compute its determinant.

In a more general context, I'm using the resultant to check if $f$ and $g$ share a root. Is there another method to check this, considering the sparsity property?

Answer (score 1):

See the oevre of I. Emiris:

*Emiris, Ioannis Z.; Pan, Victor Y.*, [**Improved algorithms for computing determinants and resultants**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jco.2004.03.003), J. Complexity 21, No. 1, 43-71 (2005). [ZBL1101.68981](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1101.68981).

*Jeronimo, Gabriela; Sabia, Juan*, [**Sparse resultants and straight-line programs**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jsc.2017.05.005),  [ZBL06825747](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:06825747).